# How many samples are required to estimate the frequency of occurrence of an output (out of 8 different outputs)?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have $N$ marbles and to each of them corresponds  a 1 or 2 or 3 or ... or 8.(i.e., there's 8 different kinds of marbles)

How many samples are required to estimate the frequency of occurrence of each kind (*within a given confidence interval and confidence level*)?

( If the answer is lengthy, a hint or a link to an online reference suffices.)

Comment: what is your distribution?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi We don't know the distribution. It's like the problem of an election poll (with 8 candidates), where you want to see how many samples is needed to predict the results within a certain confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straight forward in socio-economic statistics. An example in health care is given [here](http://bphc.hrsa.gov/policiesregulations/performancemeasures/patientsurvey/calculating.html). There also a general calculator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's for a two state problem (2 kinds of marbles). I want it for an 8 state problem.

Comment: @Monopole wouldnt the Variance for P give you a formula for sample size $S$ of number of candidates $q=8$, such as $S=q(1-q)/Var(P)$ - random sampling and Bernouli random variable assumed?